# how can i handle the has_friendship gem in my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm new into rails and I want my users to be able to befriend each other so i found the gem has_friendship [github: has_friendship](https://github.com/sungwoncho/has_friendship). I did the instructions and kinda tested everything in the rails c console. And everything worked fine. But now im kinda confused how to handle it in my application, and how to integrate it to my application. Do i need an extra friendship controller/model/view or where can i define the methods like `@user1.friend_request(@user2)` and how do i get the id of user2?

Thanks alot!

**Update**

for example: i thought about displaying every user in my user index.html.erb with a link. But how am i able to trigger the `friend_request` method by pressing this link?

`<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <h1><%= user.username %> <%= link_to "Add Friend", user_add_friend_path(:user_id) %></h1>
<%end%>`

i also edited in my routes.rb

```
  resources :users do
    get 'add_friend'
  end
```

and made a method in my users_controller.rb

```
  def add_friend
    if current_user.friend_request(@friend)
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "Friend request successfully sent."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "There was an error sending the friend request"
    end
  end
```

now i am getting a noMethod error because i did not define @friend yet. But how do i get the User i want to be befriended with?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any other model, only the user's, the gem generates a model of friendship

Simply drop in has_friendship to a model user:

```
class User <ActiveRecord :: Base
   has_friendship
end
```

Methods:

```
# @mac sends a friend request to @dee
@ mac.friend_request (@dee)

# @dee can accept the friend request
@ dee.accept_request (@mac)

# @dee can also decline the friend request
@ dee.decline_request (@mac)

# @dee removes @mac from its friends
@ dee.remove_friend (@mac)
```

They are generated by the gem

Comment: thx alot, i already did the setup but im quiet unsure how to use the methods to befriend 2 users. maybe you look at my edit.

Comment: in the user controller you must create a method, put a route to this method and change it in the link and within this method, you use the method friend_request ()

Comment: now i am getting a noMethod error because i did not define @friend yet. But how do i get the User i want to be befriended with?

Comment: I think the topic has exceeded the initial question, I would recommend that you open another topic

Answer (score 0):

Cool - sounds like a fun gem! It looks like after you run the `has_friendship` generator, you need to run a migration, which will alter your schema tables and you'll need to add `has_friendship` to your `User` model. If you can share some more code, then it will be easier for people to offer assistance.

Comment: thx alot, i already did the setup but im quiet unsure how to use the methods to befriend 2 users. maybe you look at my edit.

Comment: The gem is treating friendships as polymorphic. Based on the data tables that are automatically generated, you need to think about creating Friendship rows representing a relationship between 2 Users, rather than @friend. A single entry in the friendships table includes a "friend_id" and a "friendable_id". Check out your schema.rb file. I need to think more to figure out how I would set up the routes to create these new associations.